# aspnet core 5 route not found if deployed to Linux

Tags: asp.net-core

weird problem here.

I have an aspnet blazor app hosted on an aspnet core.

The application works well when deployed on to a Windows machine, but when deploying on to a Linux box complains that cannot find an URL. Every route that I have using the `{param_name}` fail.

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/report/summary/{m}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSummary(string m)
{
```

```cs
# Startup.cs
app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});
```

The example that Microsoft [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#endpoint) has also does not work.

```cs
  endpoints.MapGet("/hello/{name:alpha}", async context =>
                {
                    var name = context.Request.RouteValues["name"];
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync($"Hello {name}!");
                });
```

Have you guys ever come across such thing?

Comment: Have you set Kestrel URLs to listen interfaces besides localhost?

Comment: yes, although I have Nginx in front. The problem is that the blazor wasm app is capturing every request, so I am adding a link to get a file from the server with a regular <a>, but this request never reaches the server because Blazor grabs the request. I can get to the file using Postman, but not using the browser. Looks like I need to get the file in a base64 str and then blob it into a file :(